# Get data from table A according to Table B

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help...

**Table A (Operation)**

```
table_a_id
data
```

**Table B (Operation meta data)**

```
table_b_id
table_a_id
data_field_id_1
data_field_id_2
data_field_id_3
```

The user can select on a dropdown:

- meta data fields 1 as multi select option, first entry is displayed
  as "empty"
- meta data fields 2 as multi select option, first entry is displayed as "empty"

The user wants to get all operations which fits the multi select options.

**My thoughts were as follow:**

I need to get all rows from Table A,

- where table B data_field_id_1 IN (some ids)
- or table B data_field_id_2 IN (some ids)
- or table_a_id is NOT IN Table B
- or data_field_id_1 IS NULL
- or data_field_id_2 IS NULL
- or data_field_id_3 IS NULL

Can anyone help me with this SQL query?
I am getting more and more confused.

Comment: have you tried combining all the conditions you clearly mention in a sql statement?

Comment: sample data and expected results will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to show you as well the rows for which tablea has no child in tableb

```
SELECT a.table_a_id, 
  a.data 
FROM TABLEA a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLEB b ON a.table_a_id = b.table_a_id
WHERE b.data_field_id_1 IN (your ids)
  OR b.data_field_id_2 IN (your other ids)
  OR b.data_field_id_1 IS NULL
  OR b.data_field_id_2 IS NULL
  OR b.data_field_id_3 IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you! I used left join, even though I wanted first to have it done without a join... but it seems pretty fast and does all I need

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*
from tablea a join tableb b 
on a.table_a_id <> b.table_a_id
where b.data_field_id_1 IN (1,2,3) --replacement needed 
or b.data_field_id_2 IN (4,5,6) --replacement needed
-- or a.table_a_id is NOT IN Table B
or b.data_field_id_1 IS NULL
or b.data_field_id_2 IS NULL
or b.data_field_id_3 IS NULL
```

This should get you started. The tables were `join`ed based on one of your conditions `table_a_id is NOT IN Table B`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.* FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b
ON T1.table_a_id = T2.table_a_id
where T2.data_field_id_1 IN (--values)
OR T2.data_field_id_2 IN (--values)
OR T1.table_a_id is NOT IN table_b
OR T2.data_field_id_1 IS NULL
OR T2.data_field_id_2 IS NULL
OR T2.data_field_id_3 IS NULL
```

You can do JOIN but I like using LEFT JOIN to see the data side by side :-)